# How to get only specific fields with Google Directory API users.list

Tags: google-api, google-directory-api

The documentation (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list#query-parameters) says you can use `customFieldMask` to get only specific fields. I cannot figure out the format/structure of this property.

For example, given this for a user:

```
{
  "kind": "admin#directory#user",
  "id": "...",
  "etag": "\"...\"",
  "primaryEmail": "...",
  "name": {
    "givenName": "...",
    "familyName": "...",
    "fullName": "......"
  },
  "emails": [
    {
      "address": "...",
      "primary": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I only want to get `primaryEmail` but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

Send "users(primaryEmail)" in the *fields* parameter, not in the *customFieldMask* parameter.

Comment: there is no "fields" parameter in the list method

Comment: Please go to https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list, and at the "Try this method" section, click on "Show standard parameters". Then, proceed to upvote my answer.

Comment: you are completely right, I didn't know about these "standard parameters"

Answer (score 0):

The Directory API can't retrieve the 'primaryEmail' with the `customFieldMask` attribute, with this attribute you can only specify the custom schema names that you create in the Admin console.